# Who develops and maintain cPanel or WHM?

Tags: security, cpanel, web-hosting, whm, web-storage

I'm very much curious to know who develops and maintains the Cpanel/WHM/Hosting?? Is cPanel owns and maintains by any company? Is the Company/Provider design their own panel and provide the security of this..?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

WHM / cPanel is a Licensed Softare. It is developed by cPanel INC and others, you can read more on that from their [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel)

This software is installed on servers by companies who then sell space on their servers for you. When you obtain an account - they provide a cPanel account for you.

In the end you use WHM / cPanel as software, but managed and installed on a Separate Provider's Server